# Group Simple Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Having some problem grouping a simple Array. Would like to group sizes and sum quantity. These are shoe sizes.

This is my array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [sku] => '82368-21'
        [size] => 36
        [quantity] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [sku] => '82368-21'
        [size] => 36
        [quantity] => 3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [sku] => '82368-22'
        [size] => 38
        [quantity] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [sku] => '82368-23'
        [size] => 39
        [quantity] => 2
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [sku] => '82368-23'
        [size] => 39
        [quantity] => 1
    )
)
```

As you can see the shoes has multiple sizes and its quantity. There
is no need to remove any duplicates as they should all group by size.
I would like to output the following:

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [sku] => '82368-21'
        [size] => 36
        [quantity] => 4
    )


[1] => Array
    (
        [sku] => '82368-22'
        [size] => 38
        [quantity] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [sku] => '82368-23'
        [size] => 39
        [quantity] => 3
    )
)
```

Comment: What have you tried?  PS. I already solved it.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004753/single-multidimensional-array-check-with-other-index-values-php/54004904#54004904) - I think it the same question...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [single multidimensional array check with other index values php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004753/single-multidimensional-array-check-with-other-index-values-php)

Comment: @DavidWinder - it's similar but the desired output is very different.

Comment: Maybe the output is different but the way to get there is the same - I would expect the OP to do that himself. And notice that some other answer there give the same output as requested here

Comment: Sorry ya all... im not that experienced. Like Artistic said the output is a bit different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple foreach loop:

```
 $array = array (
    0 => 
    array (
        'size' => 36,
        'quantity' => 1
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
        'size' => 36,
        'quantity' => 3
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
        'size' => 38,
        'quantity' => 0
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
        'size' => 39,
        'quantity' => 2
    ),
    4 => 
    array (
        'size' => 39,
        'quantity' => 1
    )
);

$out = [];

foreach($array as $value){

    $key = $value['size'];
    if(!isset($out[$key])){
        $out[$key] = $value;
    }else{
        $out[$key]['quantity'] += $value['quantity'];
    }
}

print_r($out);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [36] => Array
        (
            [size] => 36
            [quantity] => 4
        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [size] => 38
            [quantity] => 0
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [size] => 39
            [quantity] => 3
        )

)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7c79d4f7bfe46dcfd38563b17dc3f07e282b24be)

I think the thing you were missing was using the `size` as the key.  With arrays when you want to group or combine things with a single value match, it's best to take that value and use it as the array key. That just makes it easier to find the group in the output array.  Once your done with it you can always use `array_values` to reset the keys to "normal" numbered indexs.

```
 //reset the array keys
 $out = array_values($out);
 print_r($out);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [size] => 36
            [quantity] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [size] => 38
            [quantity] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [size] => 39
            [quantity] => 3
        )

)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/26ab407c875679a06ec4c439398a6ad30bbb6750)

Cheers

Comment: This is amazing, thank you! What if I want to add another key, like my edited question. Add [sku] also..?

Comment: Oh it was added without changing anything. Thanks!